# Popup won't close

Tags: javascript

Popup won't close when i click close button, i tried debugging with console.log and it looks like `closeButton.onclick` function doesn't run at all for some reason.

When running close() function manually from the console everything works fine.

```js
class Popup {
    constructor(content){
        this.div = document.createElement("div");
        this.div.className = "block";
        //tried positioning popup into the center of the screen, doesn't work yet
        this.div.style.position = "fixed";
        this.div.style.margin = "auto auto";
        
        //caption

        this.caption = document.createElement("div");
        this.caption.style.textAlign = "right";
        
        //closeButton

        this.closeButton = document.createElement("button");
        this.closeButton.textContent = "X";
        this.closeButton.onclick = this.close;

        document.body.appendChild(this.div);
        this.div.appendChild(this.caption);
        this.caption.appendChild(this.closeButton);
        this.div.innerHTML += content;
    }
    close(){
        this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
        delete this;
    }
}

new Popup("close me");
```

That's how it looks like:

```
var popup = new Popup("hm hello");
```

[image: Popup]

---

### **SOLUTION:**

The issue was happening because:

- I was appending content of the popup right into main div using `+=`. That made DOM refresh and onclick trigger reset.
- `this.closeButton.onclick = this.close;` here onclick trigger will execute close function and also will overwrite `this` keyword, so it contains a button that called trigger, not the Popup object. I decided to put Popup into a variable that is visible to onclick function. Now everything works fine.

```js
class Popup {
    constructor(content){
        this.div = document.createElement("div");
        this.div.className = "block";
        this.div.style.position = "fixed";
        this.div.style.margin = "auto auto";
        
        //делоем капшон

        this.caption = document.createElement("div");
        this.caption.style.textAlign = "right";
        
        //кнопка закрытия

        this.closeButton = document.createElement("button");
        this.closeButton.textContent = "X";
        let popup = this;
        this.closeButton.onclick = function(){popup.close()};

        this.content = document.createElement("div");
        this.content.innerHTML = content;

        this.caption.appendChild(this.closeButton);
        this.div.appendChild(this.caption);
        this.div.appendChild(this.content);
        document.body.appendChild(this.div);
    }
    close(){
        this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
        delete this;
    }

    
}

new Popup("hello guys");
```

Comment: doesn't work, this.div.closeButton is not defined. The button is created in this.closeButton `this.closeButton = document.createElement("button");`
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined`

Comment: And (FYI), `document.body.appendChild(this.div);` should be the last line of that block. Don't append to the DOM and then immediately modify the element you just appended as it will cause unnecessary re-paint and re-flow operations.

Comment: still not working, it won't close. `this.div.closeButton = document.createElement("button");
        this.div.closeButton.textContent = "X";
        this.div.closeButton.onclick = this.close;`

Comment: Also (FYI), rather than appending and removing the element from the DOM. Just include it in the DOM to begin with but hide it (`display:none;`) and show it as necessary. Much less expensive.

Comment: @ScottMarcus How would `this.div.closeButton` be defined? A dom element cannot such a field can it?

Comment: Wait isn't this just another example of the keyword `this` being changed in the scope of a click event? Or is that just jQuery's problem?

Comment: i don't know but it defined, popup.div.closeButton returns HTML element. But popup still won't close

Comment: no, `this` keyword is not being changed because it's not inside a function

Comment: @Glublus close function is not running at all for some reason

Comment: It's probably because your constructor is not finished and thus this.close is not defined at the time of setting the onclick field? Maybe try defining the function within the constructor or directly setting it to the field just to see if it changes anything?

Comment: @Glublus sorry, i don't understand. I create DOM objects only once, div, caption and closeButton

Comment: @Glublus ok i'll try

Comment: @Glublus i tried defining close function inside constructor - still not working

Comment: @Scott Marcus i may need to show several popups at once so `display:none` is not a proper solution

Comment: I've copied your code to my computer, I'm trying some things. Are you allowed to use jquery by any chance?

Comment: @Glubus yes i can use JQuery

Comment: Alright, I discovered that the line this.div += innerHtml is supposed to be executed lastly, and it somehow blocking the clickevent from firing. Im not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that right here:

```
this.div.innerHTML += content;
```

When you assign a value to `.innerHTML`, the entire previous value is overwritten with the new value. Even if the new value contains the same HTML string as the previous value, any DOM event bindings on elements in the original HTML will have been lost. The solution is to not use `.innerHTML` and instead use `.appendChild`. To accomplish this in your case (so that you don't lose the existing content), you can create a "dummy" element that you *could* use `.innerHTML` on, but because of performance issues with `.innerHTML`, it's better to set non-HTML content up with the `.textContent` property of a DOM object.

You were also going to have troubles inside `close()` locating the correct `parentNode` and node to remove, so I've updated that.

```js
class Popup {
  constructor(content){
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.className = "block";
    this.div.style.position = "fixed";
    this.div.style.margin = "auto auto";
    
    //caption
    this.caption = document.createElement("div");
    this.caption.style.textAlign = "right";
    
    //closeButton   
    this.closeButton = document.createElement("button");
    this.closeButton.textContent = "X";
    this.closeButton.addEventListener("click", this.close);
    
    this.caption.appendChild(this.closeButton);
    this.div.appendChild(this.caption); 
    
    // Create a "dummy" wrapper that we can place content into
    var dummy = document.createElement("div");
    dummy.textContent = content;
    
    // Then append the wrapper to the existing element (which won't kill
    // any event bindings on DOM elements already present).
    this.div.appendChild(dummy);
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);
  }  
  close() {
      var currentPopup = document.querySelector(".block");
      currentPopup.parentNode.removeChild(currentPopup);
      delete this;
  }
}
    
var popup = new Popup("hm hello");
```

Comment: So instead of appending by calling `+= ` it set's it in total again, which makes a lot of sense if you think about it, though I didn't think about it when I saw it. Clearly the clickevent is unregistered, good call and good explanation overall

Comment: @Glubus Yeah `+=` has the "visual" effect of appending, but that's not what the operator actually does or means. It means "Addition with assignment". The original value is completely replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a final solution.
As Scott Marcus mentioned in his answer, i will have troubles inside close function, so i decided to put Popup object into a variable that is visible to close function. Everything works fine without applying classes. Though it may look like a bad code.

```js
class Popup {
    constructor(content){
        this.div = document.createElement("div");
        this.div.className = "block";
        this.div.style.position = "fixed";
        this.div.style.margin = "auto auto";
        
        //делоем капшон

        this.caption = document.createElement("div");
        this.caption.style.textAlign = "right";
        
        //кнопка закрытия

        this.closeButton = document.createElement("button");
        this.closeButton.textContent = "X";
        let popup = this;
        this.closeButton.onclick = function(){popup.close()};

        this.content = document.createElement("div");
        this.content.innerHTML = content;

        this.caption.appendChild(this.closeButton);
        this.div.appendChild(this.caption);
        this.div.appendChild(this.content);
        document.body.appendChild(this.div);
    }
    close(){
        this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
        delete this;
    }

    
}

new Popup("hello guys")
```

P.S.

What's the point of this restriction?
[image: restriction]

Comment: It's good that you came up with a solution for that, but this really shouldn't have been posted as an "answer", since your question wasn't really about this - it was what was why your `close` function wasn't getting called. You should delete this and simply add an "UPDATE" to your question that explains this.